# Implementing a calendar on asp.NET Web API Core using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar, asp.net-core, recurring

I'm currently implementing the back-end of an Event Scheduler. I need to input a Date Range (for example 03/07/2016-03/10/2016), a frequency ( for example "Monthly") and a termination date (12/12/2016). This should mean that the event should be scheduled every month from the 7th to the 10th until the 12th of December.

I currently have a class called Event containing the following:

```
class Event
  {
     public string Name {get; set;}
     public string Frequency {get; set;}
     public DateTime StartRange {get; set;}
     public DateTime EndRange {get; set;}
     public DateTime TerminationDate {get; set;}
  }
```

Currently, if I provide a certain range of dates, I am able to get a list of the events that will be occurring during said range.

I would like to know how i could get a list of "DateTime" objects that would provide the exact Dates the Event will occur at (in this case: if the range is from 10/01/2016 - 10/25/2016, the code would output:
         10/07/2016, 10/08/2016, 10/09/2016, and 10/10/2016)

PS: the frequencies the user can input are: Daily, Weekly, Yearly, Monthly.

Comment: look here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx#datetime_timespan
 
and here-

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar(v=vs.110).aspx